# storing datetime in session

Tags: asp.net, session, azure

I need to store a date in the session state.

On my development version, I'm using InProc session so of course, I just store the value in the session as a datetime type and it works. When I plan to release the app, I'll be upgrading initially to SQL server session and then eventually deploy the app in azure and use AppFabric to store the session state.

My question is this: can I keep the session as is or do I need to store the date as a string with ToString() to set and a parse to get the value back?

Thanks.

Comment: You do not have to do this. I am curious though, why would you want to store it as a string?

Comment: For some reason, I thought session mode other than InProc worked in key/value way, with strings as the only accepted date type.

Comment: Sessions are stored in a key/value pair, but the value is of type Object. Here is a link to MSDN on ASP.NET Sessions  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store all primitive .NET types or serializable types in session if you use external data store and any object for InProc session-state mode. So in your case, you don't have to convert to string, you can just store it as DateTime object.

Answer (score 1):

In SqlServer mode case, objects need to be serialized. Of course you can use DateTime object, but complex types need [serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attribute:

```
[Serializable]
public class ComplexClass
{
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is the serialization handled automatically?